# Story about an AI to bring down politicians

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, politics

I'm trying to identify an novel from the 80's or 90's that involved a group of political operatives traveling across an America just this side of apocalyptic.

They were protecting a depressed programmer who was building an AI interface based upon interviews with the President that would truthfully answer any question put to it as a way to bring down the current administration.  There was a ton of climate change crazy weather, and political intrigue involved.  It has stuck in my mind for years, but I just cannot remember the title or author. any help would be appreciated!